# C# code to simulate clicking on links

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, screen-scraping, web-scraping

Please take a look at [this](http://scores.covers.com/basketball-scores-matchups.aspx) website. It allows you to change the date using either the calendar or the 'next' and 'previous' links. Whenever a date is changed, the match data below is updated. I want to programmatically select a date, then retrieve the URL behind the 'Boxscore' link in the lower part.

I have tried the WebBrowser control, which often doesn't load the page fully, and if it does, I can't find a way to interact with the controls. (I'm stuck at `webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("calendar id")`). I've also tried WatiN(watin.org), which causes problems with dependencies:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3 acb5ad44e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

I'm also trying to work something out using [IeUnit](http://code.google.com/p/ieunit/), but currently I have no idea how to use it in a C# program.

Does anyone have any libraries to recommend/any other method of getting the data?

Comment: You may find people here don't advocate web-automation and / or scraping; regardless, for those who would help, you might clarify that you are allowed to do this legally.

Comment: I've done this before. You can use the WebBrowser control in C# which gives you access to all of the elements in the document (DOM). You can find link elements using the DOM and then send clicks to the links. Of course this was 5 years ago. Prob a better way by now.

Answer (score 1):

Try just sendkeys and use the tab button to move through links, enter to goto hyperlinks, and f5 to refresh.

Comment: and you can use alt+tab to select the window after running the program.

Comment: Could you clarify? How do I explicitly end a key press to a `WebBrowser` object?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/). IMHO its much better than Watin.

Download with the [C# (Selenium WebDriver)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.0rc2.zip) link.

Edit: [First tutorial](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_two_csharp_nunit.htm) that popped up on google.  Looks ok.

Comment: Can you link to the hello world example please? All would-be useful links redirect to the unorganised documentation.

Comment: Edited post.  Learn to Google son, its an invaluable skill to learn early in life.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used watin API for screen scraping, from the exception you have posted, does not reflect any problem in your code. You must be have missed a reference to the "Interop.SHDocVw.dll" file or else if you had added a reference, please do it again.

If this does not help you out then please check that .NET framework is properly installed in your machine and .dll file are there in the assembly to load from. I was getting the same problem and I solved it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question recommending HtmlUnit under .NET: [Looking for a simple C# scraping library with JavaScript support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319012/looking-for-a-simple-c-scraping-library-with-javascript-support/6325371#6325371)